# Less.css relative linking between classes

Tags: css, less

I'm writing some sort of CSS framework for personal use, and ran into a problem. If you're an experienced CSS-writer, then I'm pretty sure you're familiar with LESS.CSS. So...

I have my own color palette stored in LESS variables like so:

```
    @color-red: #...;
    @color-green: #...;
    @color-blue: #...;
```

And I assign each color to a specific class:

```
    .bg-red { background: @color-red; }
    .bg-green { background: @color-green; }
    .bg-blue { background: @color-blue; }
```

Then I have a class called `block`:

```
    .block {
         display: block;
         float: left;
         padding: 10px;
         margin: 10px;
    }
```

The purpose of the `.block:hover` thing would be to change the background of the current `block` element, and increment it - by let's say - #222. Normally, this would look something like:

```
    .block:hover {
         background: @background + #222;
    }
```

My only problem is, that we don't know what the `@background` is here, because we create the divs with `<div class="block bg-blue">` where the `bg-...` part could be anything from the color palette.

So I think I would need some kind of relative naming to target the current background. Could you help me solve this, please?

P.S.: If you think I didn't explain it correctly, just imagine if this was PHP and we were doing this in CSS/LESS:

```
    $background += 222;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once LESS is compiled, you cannot "read" what the color actually is.
However, you can use the color class instead of `.block` for the hover, since that is what your are controlling the color by. LESS makes this easy:

```
@color-red: #c00;
@color-green: #0c0;
@color-blue: #00c;

.makeHover(@color) {
   background: @color + #222;
}

.bg-red { 
    background: @color-red; 
    &:hover {.makeHover(@color-red)}
 }
.bg-green { 
    background: @color-green; 
    &:hover {.makeHover(@color-green)}
 }
.bg-blue { 
    background: @color-blue; 
    &:hover {.makeHover(@color-blue)}
 }
```

Which yields this css:

```
.bg-red {
  background: #cc0000;
}
.bg-red:hover {
  background: #ee2222;
}
.bg-green {
  background: #00cc00;
}
.bg-green:hover {
  background: #22ee22;
}
.bg-blue {
  background: #0000cc;
}
.bg-blue:hover {
  background: #2222ee;
}
```

You could also [use a built in color function for the darkening](http://lesscss.org/#-color-functions).

If you actually want more generic css, then do something with pseudo classes [like this fiddle demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/6Nzke/3/). If only CSS3 browsers are targeted, then you can eliminate the `:before` element in that fiddle and use `rgba()` color format on the `background` of the `.block` element.

Comment: This is actually helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From my research and using LESS daily here at work. I do not believe there is a way to get a color of an element after it has been processed just by using LESS. I'm guessing you will have to use Jquery or some sort of scripting to do this.

Here is a plugin that has a lot of tools to manipulate colors. [jQuery color plugin xcolor](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/#meth_multiply)

You may also need another function to convert the found RGB element color to hex so you can add your other color to it. [Jquery convert RGB to HEX colour values](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-convert-rgb-hex-color/#.T_aVsCITFow)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh... Thanks, but now it just bugs me more. I mean, I don't think this is such a rare situation. There must be a solution in LESS I think. Thanks for your comment though, unfortunately jQuery and JavaScript is all gibberish to me, I never used any of them before.

Comment: I hope you find what you need. If do happen to figure it out please post it back here so we use it :)